# How to resolve issue on my wordpress site that's showing the 500 error?

Tags: php, wordpress

My WP website, esawang.com displays error 500. And I can't login to the backend, I only access it via the file manager. I also noticed that the wp-config.php file is empty. I can't really tell what's responsible for it.

I've tried different ways to resolve the issue but it still did not work out. I've disabled all the plugins one by one, disabled the theme, and uploaded fresh WP folders (wp-admin and wp-includes) to overrite the old ones but it still didn't work.

Below is the latest error message in error.log

```
Stack trace:
#0 /home2/esawang/public_html/index.php(17): require()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home2/esawang/public_html/wp-blog-header.php on line 16
```

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Do you have backup of site?? its happen uncertainly? see there we will be lots of causes I will mention some of them you figure it out. 1) while updating plugins or disrupt update 2) white updating theme/ template 3) bad syntax and coding 4) outdated plugins.. this check it out properly.. enabled disabled your plugin check cross which plugin is cause for this.. if u know exact plugin then zip/remove it from file manager..

Answer (score 0):

**Go to this file**

```
/home2/esawang/public_html/wp-blog-header.php
```

**changes like this**

```
<?php

define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

?>
```